# How to view attribute values in Microsoft.Xrm.Data.Powershell?

Tags: powershell, dynamics-crm

I am using this command:

```
Get-CrmEntityAttributes contact | Select-Object -First 1
```

[image]

For some properties instead of a value it shows:

1. System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject
2. Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Metadata.AttributeRequiredLevelManagedProperty
3. Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.BooleanManagedProperty
4. Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Label

Please guide how to view readl data as a text?

Answer (score 1):

That's because all these properties are complex objects with their specific data type. They have more than one properties.

You have to explore these object for properties and find the ones you need and then select data set with expressions for sub object properties.

See what data contains in `Description` (`Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Label`) property. Find the ones you need.

```
$item = Get-CrmEntityAttributes contact | Select-Object -First 1
$item.Description
```

Then make sub expression for result objects. Like so:

```
$item = Get-CrmEntityAttributes contact | Select-Object -First 1
$item | Select -Property Property1,Property2,Property3,@{label='Description';expression={$_.Description.LocalizedLabels.ToString()}},Property4,Property5
```

I hope you have got the point.